# Rack:cors gem not setting cors header for GET requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rack-cors

I am trying to use Rack-cors gem to enable cors. The issue is that for non-get requests the header is coming bur for GET requests the header is not present.

In `application.rb`

```
    config.middleware.insert_before ActionDispatch::Static, Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins '*.example.com'
        resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
      end
    end
```

- [Searched rack:cors issue](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors/issues/33) but not able to found any solution .

Any idea what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Its working for me. Having following configuration in application.rb

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
  allow do
    origins *Rails.application.secrets.cors_origins
    resource '/posts', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :options]
    resource '/post', headers: :any, methods: [:post, :options]
  end
end
```

Comment: What version of rails and rails-api are you using?

Comment: rails (4.2.6) , rails-api (0.4.0)

Comment: Not sure why this is not working for me.. I am using Rails 3.2.13 and not using rails-api.